# Can't apply filter to dynamic column in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-table

I'm building an application in React where I have a column built dynamically based on the value of other columns, but for some reason I can't apply a filter to this dynamic column, but in the other columns the filter works perfectly.

```
export const COLUMNS =  [
    {
        Header: 'Computer',
        accessor: 'Computer',
        Filter: ColumnFilter,
        disableSortBy: true,
        style: {'whiteSpace': 'unset'}
          
    },
    {
        Header: 'Platform',
        accessor: 'Platform',
        Filter: ColumnFilter,
        disableSortBy: true
    },
    {
        Header: 'Agent Version',
        accessor: 'Agent Version',
        Filter: ColumnFilter,
        disableSortBy: true
    },
    {
        Header: 'Policy Name',
        accessor: 'Policy Name',
        Filter: ColumnFilter,
        disableSortBy: true
    },
    {
        Header: 'Severity',
        accessor: 'Severity',
        disableSortBy: true,
        Cell: ({ row }) => {
           if(row.original['Agent Version'] !== '0.0.0.0'){
                if(
                row.original['Anti-Malware Enabled'] !== 'YES' |
                row.original['Machine Learning Enabled'] !== 'YES'  |
                row.original['Behavior Monitoring Enabled'] !== 'YES' | 
                row.original['Backup and Restore Files Enabled'] !== 'YES' & row.original['Platform'].includes('Windows') | 
                row.original['Scan Compressed Files Enabled'] !== 'YES' |
                row.original['Web Reputation Enabled'] !== 'YES' |
                row.original['Action for Behavior Monitoring'] !== 'YES' 
                
                ){
                    return row.original['Severity'] = "Critical"
                }else if(
                    
                    row.original['ScanActionForAmsi'] !== 'YES' & row.original['Platform'].includes('Windows')
                    ){
                    return row.original['Severity'] = "Warning"
    
                }else{
                    return row.original['Severity'] = "No Issues"
                    
                }
        }else{
            return row.original['Severity'] = "No Data"
           
        }
    }
    
    },]
```

[image]

Comment: Because you did not define the `Filter` attribute for that `Severity`

Comment: Even when I add it Filter: ColumnFilter, it fails to filter

Comment: Please kindly show your `ColumnFilter` here as well.